# Checking a successful .delete() in IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I was wondering if anyone has figured out how to 'correctly' check if the `delete()` functionality in IndexedDB actually successfully deleted a record.

I found this:

```
// As per spec http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#object-store-deletion-operation
// the result of the Object Store Deletion Operation algorithm is
// undefined, so it's not possible to know if some records were actually
// deleted by looking at the request result.
```

Is it just a matter of saving the record key before deleting, deleting the record and then checking if the record is in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `.onsuccess` handler to the request object returned by the `.delete` method if it fires the object should have been deleted. You can also add a `.onerror` handler to handle cases where there is a problem deleting the object from the store.

You could of course save the key and check the store afterward in the `.onsuccess` handler but that should not be necessary; if the request succeeded, it succeeded.

Be careful if you are doing more than one thing on that transaction, a `.onsuccess` handler attached to the delete request will fire as soon as the item has been deleted, **but** if you do another operation on the same transaction and that other operation fails, the entire transaction will get rolled back, including the deletion. In that case it would be better to add a `.onsuccess` handler to the transaction so you can be sure that all the operations succeeded.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the quote above mean that regardless if the `onsuccess` is triggered the `delete` may not have succeeded?

Comment: IndexedDB uses [atomic transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_transaction). `onsuccess` fires because the deletion **did** succeed, it may be _rolled back_ after succeeding if another operation on the same transaction fails. Again this only matters if you do more than one operation on the transaction; if you create a transaction just for the delete and do not do anything else on the transaction the transaction will not have any chance of failing when the delete succeeds.

Comment: Does this apply to the `add()` method as well?  Because it is also mentioned that even though the `onsuccess` is triggered does not necessarily mean that it was "successful".

Comment: Yes, all transactions in IndexedDB are atomic, if you do more than one operation per transaction it is possible that one of them will fail and cause the entire transaction to be rolled back.

Comment: It was successfully deleted. The only problem is your key may not exist in the store. In that case, you also receive `onsuccess` event, although nothing is deleted.

Comment: oh ok.  So checking to see if the key exists before hand will take care of this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: _"In that case it would be better to add a .onsuccess handler to the transaction"_ -- Just for the record, I think you mean an `oncomplete` handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if object exist with the get command on object store, you can retrieve the object id when you delete the object.

```
function checkIfObjectExist(objectID){
    var request = indexedDB.open(baseName);
    request.onsuccess = function() {
        var db = request.result;
        var transaction = db.transaction(objectStoreName, 'readonly');
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectStoreName);
        var selectRequest = objectStore.get(objectID);
        selectRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
            if (e.target.result != null) {
                console.log("Object Exist");
            }else{
                console.log("Object doesn't exist");
            }
        }

    }
}
```